# Limit of a formula to find the closest number to a prime less than an even number in given range

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let's say the 'closest' is the diff between the number get by the formula  and a prime less than $1$, and define samples:

$f1(n) = n - 1$

$f2(n) = n - \left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor^2 + \frac{\pi}{4}\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor^2$

$f3(n) = n - \left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor^2 + \left(\frac{4 \times \sqrt{2}}{7} - \frac{15}{28} \right)\pi\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor^2$

$... , n\in \mathbb{2N}$

For example $f1(6) = 5$, which closest to a  prime number $5$ that less an $6$.

As Ivan Neretin commented: Any formula will do the same.

Check the first $500$ even numbers, $f1$ give $167$ closest numbers, $f2$ give $171$ closest numbers and $f3$ give $173$ closest numbers,maybe $fx$ give $373$ closest numbers.

My question is: for a given range, dose these kind of formulas has a limit less than the legth of the range of the 'closest'? That is maybe we can say for the first $50$ even numbers, we cant find a formula that give closest numbers exceed $45$.

Comment: What makes you think that the integer part of $f(n)$ is a prime for all $n$? It does work for your two examples but I see no reason why this should hold in general.

Comment: @quarague that's not  a prime number, only close to a prime number, that is the diff is not that large.

Comment: My question is why would you think that it is close to a prime number? In both your examples $f(n)$ is between two integers, one of them is even and the other is prime. In general I don't think there needs to be a prime anywhere close to $f(n)$ for some $n$.

Comment: @quarague I see your question, this  only  is a try, sometimes the diff maybe large $f(1e18) = 855794185953105763.4$, and the primes are $855794185953105709, 855794185953105719, 855794185953105809$

Comment: Then what the formula is good for? What does it give? A number that is at some unspecified distance from a prime? ***Any*** formula will do the same.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin Thanks, I updated this question.

Comment: your formula simplifies to $$f(n) = n + \left(\frac{16\pi \times \sqrt{2}-\pi 15-28}{28}\right)\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor^2,  n\in \mathbb{2N}$$

Comment: This appears to be an exact duplicate of MathOverflow's [Limit of formulas to find the closest number to a prime less than an even number in given range](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347114/limit-of-formulas-to-find-the-closest-number-to-a-prime-less-than-an-even-number) that was asked just a few hours later. You should try to avoid cross-posting too quickly. Also, when you do cross-post, you should always indicate you did. Thanks.